# Building Mosquitto MQTT auth plugin issue

Tags: mosquitto, libmosquitto

I need an advanced auth for Mosquitto. I decided to use [mosquitto-auth-plug](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug)

However, if I follow the [build instructions](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug#building-the-plugin) I have the error:

```
$ make
Selected backends:          JWT
Using mosquitto source dir: /mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15
OpenSSL install dir:

If you changed the backend selection, you might need to 'make clean' first

CFLAGS:   -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include
LDFLAGS:   -L/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/
LDADD:    -lcurl -L/lib -lcrypto -lmosquitto

cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -c -o auth-plug.o auth-plug.c
cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -c -o base64.o base64.c
cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -c -o pbkdf2-check.o pbkdf2-check.c
cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -c -o log.o log.c
cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -c -o envs.o envs.c
cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -c -o hash.o hash.c
cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -c -o be-psk.o be-psk.c
cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -c -o backends.o backends.c
cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -c -o cache.o cache.c
cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -c -o be-jwt.o be-jwt.c
cc  -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/src/ -I/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_JWT  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/include   -L/mnt/c/Users/avkar/cleversky/mosquitto/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/ -fPIC -shared -o auth-plug.so auth-plug.o base64.o pbkdf2-check.o log.o envs.o hash.o be-psk.o backends.o cache.o be-jwt.o   -lcurl -L/lib -lcrypto -lmosquitto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmosquitto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'auth-plug.so' failed
make: *** [auth-plug.so] Error 1
```

Somewhat `-lmosquitto` not found.
I have assumed that is a library, but all librares present:

```
$ ls ../mosquitto-1.4.15/lib/
CMakeLists.txt  logging_mosq.c  memory_mosq.h    mosquitto.h           net_mosq.h            read_handle_shared.c  socks_mosq.c   time_mosq.c  util_mosq.c
cpp             logging_mosq.h  messages_mosq.c  mosquitto_internal.h  read_handle.c         send_client_mosq.c    socks_mosq.h   time_mosq.h  util_mosq.h
dummypthread.h  Makefile        messages_mosq.h  mqtt3_protocol.h      read_handle_client.c  send_mosq.c           srv_mosq.c     tls_mosq.c   will_mosq.c
linker.version  memory_mosq.c   mosquitto.c      net_mosq.c            read_handle.h         send_mosq.h           thread_mosq.c  tls_mosq.h   will_mosq.h
```

What is the `-lmosquitto` and how can I fix my build?

Comment: Did you build the mosquitto source first? What you have shown is the mosquitto source not the built output.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll try to build mosquitto source first, but anyway what `-lmosquitto` stands for?

Comment: It tells the compiler/linker to link libmosquitto.so into the output

Comment: No, the the result is the same

Comment: Did you install mosquitto after building it (or have you installed mosquitto and libmosquitto)

Comment: @hardillb you was right from the beging. I didn't install assembled mosquitto and that was the problem. `cd mosquitto-1.4.15 && sudo make install` solved my problem. You may post your answer, it is the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hashed out in the comments,

You need to build and install mosquitto (or install the prebuilt version and it's dev package) before trying to build the plugin.

The error is because ld can not find libmosquitto to link against